# pandas grouper vs time grouper

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, datetimeindex

The new pandas version deprecates the `TimeGrouper`, so we should use the regular `Grouper`.

The old code:

```
df['column_name'].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("M")).mean().plot()
```

works fine in the old version of pandas. However, none of:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='column_name', freq="M")).mean().plot()
df['column_name'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).mean().plot()
```

works in the new version.
Eiter the key is considered to be missing, or pandas complains about:

```
Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Float64Index'
```

## edit

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column_name':['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02'],
                  'column_value':[1,3]})

df

df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.column_name)

df.index

# old version
df['column_value'].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("M")).mean().plot()

# new version
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='column_value', freq="M")).mean().plot()
```

Comment: If the key column is not a datetime then grouper with freq attribute wont work .

Comment: But that was already true for the old version. So the code snippet should not have worked in the first place? assuming that the index would be a regular range index.

Comment: Oh sorry I agree. Can you add example data so we try to reproduce the same.

Comment: You are not converting column_name to be datetime so grouper wont work. Its not about the index its about the key column.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I said in the comment key should be datetime in grouper. Timegrouper by default converts it to datetime so use

```
df['column_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column_name'])
# new version
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='column_name', freq="M")).mean().plot()
```